# Connecting DC 0V to mains earth

Tags: power-supply, grounding, emc

Using the picture below as an example. What's the standard convention?

- Link 0V of DC supply to chassis/mains earth
- Have the 0V of the DC supply not connected to the chassis in any way

If it depends on the circumstances what's the better option in terms of reducing EMI and noise on the digital circuit

[image]

Comment: What else is connected to the digital circuit and/or dc supply? Usually EMI *susceptibility* issues are more about the (essential) holes in your dashed boxes and AC connections (for example, the DC supply probably has an AC short from input to output if it's a switching type)

Comment: The DC supply is a self made, transformer, bridge, capacitor type power supply which has 3 outputs +/-9V and 0V. The digital circuit is essentially an FPGA which processes incoming SPI information from an ADC and relays it out to a PC via a USB connection...

Comment: ... The reason behind this question is that the USB connector for the chassis has a metal ring which allows the connector to be grounded or not, the problem is that grounding the USB connector in turn, grounds the digital circuit and therefore the DC supply. [Picture of USB Connector](https://thumbs4.static-thomann.de/thumb/bdbmagic/pics/bdb/182683/9600119_800.jpg)

Comment: Is the shield actually connected internally to the ground pin on that USB connector?

Comment: The shield isn't connected internally, however, it connects the shield to the chassis. On my digital board is a SMT mini USB connector which connects the shield to the ground plane. So my board (If my thinking is correct) is technically using the shield of the USB cable as a grounding wire.

Comment: the shield and ground of usb are not always connected.

Comment: @dandavis I'm aware the shield and ground are not always connected, however in this case the shield *does* connect the ground plane of the PCB to the chassis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both possibilities you mention can be valid choices, depending on the situation.  However, don't connect the AC line ground and the local ground as your diagram shows.  In equipment that is enclosed in a metal chassis, the AC line ground wire is usually connected to the chassis.  Line and neutral are always considered "hot", even though, in theory, neutral isn't supposed to have any voltage on it.

One issue is creating a ground loop.  For movable equipment, you just connect the chassis to the AC line ground.  However, for fixed mounted equipment, you may have the option of connecting to a local ground.

Connecting the local ground and AC line ground is not a good idea as this can cause a ground loop.  In such a case, it is usually better to connect the outer chassis to the local ground.  The frame of a power supply might still be connected to the AC line ground, but then that shouldn't be shorted to the chassis.  Or, you ignore the AC line ground completely and tie the power supply frame and whole chassis to the local ground.

Some power supplies are themselves insulated and only have two AC input connections.  Those completely get around this problem because there is no place to connect the ground to.

Comment: I wanted to use a panel mount type USB connector on the chassis [This type](https://thumbs4.static-thomann.de/thumb/bdbmagic/pics/bdb/182683/9600119_800.jpg) which has a metal ring for grounding which is removable. The digital circuit will use this USB connector and therefore can or cannot be connected to the chassis as I desire. In that case is it better to have the USB connector not connected to the chassis as this would cause a ground loop? Or is this not a problem as long as I remove the link between the AC ground and local ground

Comment: @Doodle: If the USB equipment is floating, connect the ground on your end.  If the other end is a fixed installation that is also grounded, it gets more tricky.  Sometimes I've put 100 Ohms in series with the shield, but that's not necessarily optimum either.